# Glassfy permission never gets valid

Tags: flutter, dart, in-app-purchase

I'm trying to add Glassfy to my Flutter app. The process works well, I get subscribed, I can see it on the Glassfy dahsboard and even in Play Store under the subscriptions. But somehow, the permission never gets valid.

Here is the fnction where the `permission.isValid!` part will never executed.

```
onClickedSku: (sku) async {
              final transaction = await PurchaseApi.purchaseSku(sku: sku);
          if (!mounted) {
            return;
          }
          if (transaction != null) {
            final permissions = transaction.permissions!.all!;
            final permission = permissions.firstWhere(
                (permission) => permission.permissionId == 'premium'); 
            if (permission.isValid!) {
              ref.read(glassfyProvider.notifier).state = true;
            }
          }
        }
```

and this one is the `PurchaseApi.purchaseSku` method:

```
static Future<GlassfyTransaction?> purchaseSku(
      {required GlassfySku sku}) async {
    try {
      return await Glassfy.purchaseSku(sku);
    } catch (e) {
      debugPrint(e.toString());
      return null;
    }
  }
```

My app is in an initial testing state right now. I've tested it on emulator and a real device as well.

Comment: Have you confirmed the `sku` you're purchases has been configured on the `premium` permission in their dashboard?